# Is "Why-Man" an alien or an AI?

Tags: dr.stone

So I just finished Dr. Stone, and the ending was kinda confusing to me. After being able to understand all of the terminology and understanding the theory of what happens, I can't seem to understand the ending. Was "Why-Man" an alien from space or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the ending was left somewhat ambiguous. It is mentioned that they are artificial lifeforms, however even they do not know who or what made them, just like the humans that went to the moon.

[image]